# Drag to change value

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag

Any tips on how I can make it possible to drag the `div .handle` across the `div .slider` and get a value when doing so? Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Drag to see price</title>
        <meta name="description" content="En interaktiv genomgång av Brackets.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider{
    background-color: black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 15px;
}

.handle{
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: -0px;
    width: 56px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    height: 32px;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered `input type=range`?

Comment: Thanks alot, well that was easier than expected! ;)

Comment: input type=range isn't compatible with IE9 and earlier. Users on Windows Vista will be stuck with a textbox if you do that.

If anybody was curious about how to make a handmade slider, here's something to start. http://jsfiddle.net/xxqunusu/

Answer (score 1):

If you're only catering to IE9 and earlier, consider simply using the HTML5 input:

[image]

```js
$("#test").on("input change",function(){
  $("#bleh").text($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="range"/>
<p id="bleh"></p>
```

Else, you probably have to implement your own solution or use something like [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr)

Comment: PS: I don't think he's using JQuery.

Comment: jQuery isn't required to use the `range` input, I just included it so the value the slider is set to is visible.

Comment: What I meant is that I would do it in vanilla JS since the asker didn't tag his question with JQuery and didn't mention JQuery.